# Render form with local variable in js erb file rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, erb

Hi I'm trying to render a form in a modal using bootstrap 4 but I'm getting this error

```
undefined local variable or method `task' for #<# 
<Class:0x007f8aedbd9730>:0x007f8af4511d10>
```

### app/views/messages/new.js.erb, line 3

When I try to use the form on my haml view it works perfectly

```
 - checklist.tasks.each_with_index do |task, index|
   = task.description
   = render 'messages/form', current_company_task: task.company_tasks.find_or_create_by(company: @company).id
```

When I try to make this as a modal instead of doing the above code I do this:

```
- checklist.tasks.each_with_index do |task, index|
  =task.description
  = link_to 'New Message', new_message_path, {remote: true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => "#dialog-#{index}", 'data-backdrop' => 'static', 'data-keyboard' => 'true'}
```

Now on my **new.js.erb** It's like this

```
$('.modal-body').html('<%= j render("form", current_company_task: task.company_tasks.find_or_create_by(company: @company).ids) %>');
```

It is the same call but I don't know why is not working under my js.erb file
Btw my modal is working, it is the form the one that is not rendering on that modal. But why the variable is working under my view but not on my js.erb file?

Comment: you didn't pre-assign `task` in new.js.erb, hence the error message

Comment: But where should I assign it, is it on my view in the link_to or where should I put that?

Comment: what view was `render 'messages/form', current_company_task: task.company_tasks.find_or_create_by(company: @company).id`  on?new.html.haml?

Comment: `task` should be assigned in MessagesController `new` action, and it should be instance variable

Comment: But task is under a loop, i cannot use it as an instance variable under that controller

Comment: when you render the form inside modal, `task` is not in the loop anymore

Comment: Oh thanks, at the end I passed the task.id parameters to the link and now I can create a @task variable under the controller